# Hibernate Insert Query in Java

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

Can anyone tell me how to perform an insert query with Hibernate and back end postgresql
I am using the following implementation but not working

```
Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();

User A= new User();
A.setId(67);
A.setFirstName("Noor");
A.setLastName("asd");
A.setMobileNumber("2435");
A.setTelephoneNumber("dfg");

session.save(A);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using [`EntityManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html)?

Comment: are you getting any error messages? Or does it just not do anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Matt Ball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139010/matt-ball) suggested, try using `EntityManager.persist(java.lang.Object entity)` ([see here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#persist%28java.lang.Object%29)) instead. Or simply try using persist without EntityManager ([see this discussion](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2325758&sid=a69cf62ab0451699a62552ac473356a7)).